# Comment dit-on « How was your week? » en français?

Tags: usage

Je dirais « Comment était ta semaine ? », mais je crois que ce n'est pas naturel. Comment un francophone le dirait-il ?

Comment: J’ai fait quelques corrections à ton message, n’hésite pas à poser des questions pour savoir lesquelles. En particulier, attention à ne pas confondre « parler » (to speak) et « dire » (to say).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> How was your week

Peut se traduire par

> Comment s'est passée ta semaine ?

ou effectivement comme tu le suggères:

> Comment était ta semaine ?

Cependant en français j'ai la sensation que la première forme au passé composé montre plus de sympathie que la seconde qui sera plus formelle et moins amicale.

PS: je suis francophone

Comment: @FredP on peut être Francophone et nul en orthographe j'en suis la preuve, mais en postant ici, je devrais faire attention.

Comment: euh, oui... euh... comment dire... tu devrais :-O

Comment: merci pour le passé simple @stephanegimenez

Comment: +1 pour la premiere forme.  (Ce que j'entends le plus souvent c'est "C'est passée comment, ta semaine?")

Comment: La même tournure s'applique à pas mal de situations: "comment était ta soirée d'hier ?", "comment était ton weekend ?"... En revanche, on dira plus volontiers "comment s'est passé ton examen ?" (how do **you** feel about your exam) même si tout le monde comprendra "comment était ton examen ?" (how was your exam, i.e. difficult or not; exam is the subject in this sentence).

Answer (score 4):

La forme que je trouve la plus naturelle, que j'utilise et que j'entends le plus souvent :

> Ta semaine s'est bien passée ?

Concernant les autres propositions je trouve les formulations avec « *comment* » trop lourdes et trop formelles.

Answer (score 2):

Dans un contexte plus informel, on entend rarement ça. On dira plus facilement :

> Alors, ta semaine ?

Qui sous-entend, "comment s'est passée ta semaine ?"

Mais plus généralement, on s'intéressera à ce qu'il a *fait* pendant cette fameuse semaine :

> As-tu bien profité de tes vacances ?
>
> Le boulot, ça va (cette semaine) ?

etc.

Answer (score 1):

Ne serait-ce que pour contribuer aux diverses propositions déjà utiles, la forme la plus courante ici¹, bien que probablement incorrecte (ce qui, en l'occurrence, ne décourage en aucun cas son usage) est :

> Comment ça a été ta semaine ?

(prononcé avec une quasi-fusion des deux *a*, on entend un *a* et demi si je puis dire)

¹ à Nancy (Lorraine)

Comment: Il est drôle de voir comment quelques de kilomètres peuvent influencer une langue.